# Paypal Sucess Url Not Working : Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

My first question on codeigniter. I have integrated paypal in codeigniter using paypal library. everything working fine but when I return to success page then it gave me "An Error Occurred :  The action you performed is not valid".  But the same success page is accessible directly from the url (I mean when I put it in the browser directly).

**Controller**

```
function form()
{
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('business', 'xxxxxxx@ymail.com');
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', site_url('checkout/paypal/success'));
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', site_url('checkout/paypal/cancel'));
$this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', site_url('checkout/paypal/ipn')); 
$this->paypal_lib->
add_field($this->security->csrf_token_name,   $this->security->csrf_hash); 
}
function success()
{
  echo "success";
}
```

**Routes**

```
$route['checkout/paypal'] = 'checkout/paypal/index';
$route['checkout/paypal/(:any)'] = "checkout/paypal/$1";
```

Success page is diretly accessible and prints "success" but when I return from paypal , it gave me "An Error Occurred"

In the apache log..getting 500 572. I am not pretty much sure what it reflects.

Thanks

Comment: Did you correctly configure your API keys in CodeIgniter and the IPN/Return URI on the paypal interface ?

Comment: I am sorry UGO, But I dont know about API keys.I simply downloaded the paypal library and then changed the parameters according to my success/cancel/ipn. Please update where should I neeed to change.

Comment: You're dealing with a payment API, you'll have some work to do ! Read the documentation of the library you downloaded and the Paypal API documentation.

Comment: I am sure about this that there is nothing left in the installation/configuration of the API. I am successfully getting the IPN at my testing sandbox account. The Only Problem is with the Success page loading after returning from Paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your site's main configuration file and check your CSRF settings. I had a similar problem once, and it was solved by disabling CSRF protection.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Does that make any difference?

Comment: You are absolutely right Tim. I already sorted out , I was going to answer myself. :) :) But then I found , you have already answered this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Above code will do trick in that situation, although you shouldn't turn that off,
so in that case:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;

$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('controller/success_function');
```

will also do the trick.